# How to set a proxy api token as auth on hackney through HTTPoison?

Tags: proxy, erlang, elixir, httpoison

I'm having a problem authenticating on Crawlera service using HTTPoison.

The crawlera's API documentation says I only need the API Token.

i.e. `curl -vx proxy.crawlera.com:8010 -U <API key>: http://httpbin.org/ip`

So, I'm having problems setting the authentication options on HTTPoison settings.

I'm trying this 3 options:

`HTTPoison.get("url", header, hackney: [:insecure], proxy: 'proxy.crawlera.com:8010', proxy_auth: 'api-token')`

Error -> `(FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :hackney.do_connect/7`

`HTTPoison.get("url", header, hackney: [:insecure], proxy: 'proxy.crawlera.com:8010', proxy_auth: {'api-token',''})`

Error -> `(ArgumentError) argument error :erlang.bit_size([])`

`HTTPoison.get("url", header, hackney: [:insecure], proxy: 'api-token:@proxy.crawlera.com:8010')`

Error -> `{"X-Crawlera-Error", "bad_proxy_auth"}`

If someone knows how to set correctly the parameters I'll appreciate the help.

Comment: Try `proxy: "proxy.crawlera.com:8010", proxy_auth: {"api-token", ""}` (your second snippet with single quotes changed to double quotes).

Comment: Actually, try this instead: `proxy: {"proxy.crawlera.com", 8010}, proxy_auth: {"api-token", ""}`. The port needs to be separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `proxy` argument should be a tuple of the host and port.
2. You need to use binaries instead of charlists for the host and both the elements of `proxy_auth`.

The following should work:

```
proxy: {"proxy.crawlera.com", 8010}, proxy_auth: {"api-token", ""}
```